# comparing strings in an ArrayList. Case Sensative

Tags: java, arraylist, case

This is my first post.  I have spent hours trying to work out how I can compare my String i.e. `word` to all my `ArrayList` elements, checking if they are equal, disregarding case.

Here is my code.

```
private static void writeFile(Scanner scanWords, ArrayList<String> wordList,
  FileWriter fo, BufferedWriter out) throws IOException {
    String word = null;
    int count = 0;
    boolean contains=false;
    String temp = "";

    for(int i = 0; i<wordList.size();i++){

        while(scanWords.hasNext()){
            word= scanWords.next();

            if(wordList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(word)){
                contains = true;
            }else{
                System.out.println(word);
                out.write(word);
                //out.write(word);
            }
        }
    }
    count++;
    out.close();
}
```

Any help given would be amazing.

Answer (score 3):

First, convert your `List<String>` to a `HashSet` of case insensitive strings - i.e. all lower case (using the `String.toLowerCase()` method). Then you can use the `Collection.contains()` method

e.g.

```
List<String> strings;
Set<String> lowerCaseStrings = new HashSet<String>(strings.size());
for (String str : strings){
  lowerCaseStrings.add(str.toLowerCase());
}
boolean match = lowerCaseString.contains(myStr.toLowerCase());
```

EDIT: Was suggesting using `ArrayList<String>`, but should be `HashSet<String>` - see comments below.

Comment: Ok this looks promising, i might give this a go.

Comment: This really helped thanks,  My program was also looping incorectly.  using a temp array was a good idea.  Cheers.  One question tho.  Why wouldnt lowerCaseString.equalsToIgnoreCase() not work.  ?  Is it becuase an array list simply hold the memory location of the string, not the string itself.  Ergo you cant make a memory location equal to another ?

Comment: `"String".toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase( "stRiNg" )` works and is `true`, for sure, unless the `"StringX"` contains characters not present in `"stRinNgY"` or the char sequences are different.

Comment: -1: unless you have many words to find in the same list, this is an inefficient way of doing. And if many words must be found in the same list, then the collection of lower-case words should be a HashSet (O(1) lookups) instead of a List (O(n) lookups)

Comment: @JBNizet - you're right, it should be a HashSet. Amended accordingly. However, I would still do it this way - in the approach in your answer (whilst I like the separation of concerns), you have to iterate through the entire list for each String from the Scanner, whereas this was intended to reduce the number of iterations through the List - but of course, as you've pointed out, that efficiency is only gained when it's a HashSet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you're trying to do 3 different things, in the wrong order, in the same method:

- write to a file
- find a word in a list
- read words from a scanner

Each of these operations should be a separate one. Regarding what you asked for:

> how I can compare my String i.e. word to all my ArrayList elements,
>   checking if they are equal, disregarding case

This is one part of your complete program that should be in its own method (the second bullet in the above list). You don't need a Scanner and a FileWriter and a BufferedWriter for this. All you need is the word and the list. And the method should return a boolean:

```
public boolean listContainsWordIgnoringCase(List<String> list, String word) {
```

And the implementation is very easy:

```
public boolean listContainsWordIgnoringCase(List<String> list, String word) {
    for (String element : list) {
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(element)) {
            // no need to continue looping. We've found the answer
            return true;
        }
    }
    // we've looped through all the elements without finding a match
    return false;
}
```

Now this method can be used in your program.

The trick is to separate the logic in simple blocks which only have one responsibility. And make a method for each of this block.

Answer (score 0):

> *how i can compare my String i.e. `word` to all my `ArrayList` elements ...*

It seems, you are using `scanWords` scanner object incorrectly.

Using your code, if first element of your `wordsList` does not match with any of `scanWords` elements, then none of the elements in `wordsList` will be processed for comparison. Why because, to compare with first word in the list, you have iterated till the end of `scanWords` which causes a next call to `hasNext()` always return a `false`.

Following is a fix to your requirement:

```
while ( scanWords.hasNext() ) {
  word= scanWords.next();
  //for( int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++ ) {
  for( String wordInList : wordList ) {
    if( wordInList.equalsIgnoreCase( word ) ) {
      contains = true;
    } else {
      System.out.println( word );
      out.write( word );
    }
  } // for list
} // while scanner
```

---

***Solution 2***:

> *I tried this method before, the problem is it loops through the same word 6 times. 6 being the size of my arraylist.*

Here is a simple solution without explicit looping on list elements.

```
String listElements = wordList.toString().toLowerCase();  
while ( scanWords.hasNext() ) {  
  word = scanWords.next();  
  if ( listElements.contains( word.toLowerCase() ) ) {  
    contains = true;  
  } else {  
    System.out.println( word );  
    out.write( word );  
  }  
} // while scanner
```

---

***Sample Execution***:

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>( 4 );
ls.add( "raVi" );
ls.add( "sreekaR" );
ls.add( "lakShMi" );
ls.add( "sumAna" );

String listElements = ls.toString();
System.out.println( "listElements: " + listElements );
System.out.println( "listElements.toLowerCase(): " + listElements.toLowerCase() );
scanner = new Scanner( "Ravi Sumana Others sREEKar LAKshmi" );
while( scanner.hasNext() ) {
  String w1 = scanner.next();
  System.out.println( "'" + w1 + "' is in list ? = " + listElements.toLowerCase().contains( w1.toLowerCase() ) );
}
```

And the result on execution is:

```
listElements: [raVi, sreekaR, lakShMi, sumAna]
listElements.toLowerCase(): [ravi, sreekar, lakshmi, sumana]
'Ravi' is in list ? = true
'Sumana' is in list ? = true
'Others' is in list ? = false
'sREEKar' is in list ? = true
'LAKshmi' is in list ? = true
```

Comment: I tried this method before, the problem is it loops through the same word 6 times.  6 being the size of my arraylist.

Comment: @user1419012 You mean, looking a solution without looping in the list?